# Polymer get element by id from shadow root

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, polymer, clojurescript

I am not able to get an element by id that is in the shadow root. It will return nil. Here is the code. It is written in clojurescript.

```
    (p/defpolymer :query-component {:imports  ["components/polymer/polymer.html"]
                            :style    ".query-container
                             {margin: 20px;
                             display: inline-block;}"
                            :template [[:div.query-container
                                        [:div
                                         [:h4 {:style "display: inline-block;"} "Current Query"]
                                         [:button {:style    "float: right; margin-top: 10px;"
                                                   :on-click "{{runQuery}}"} "Run Query"]]
                                        [:span "{{query.name}}"]
                                        [:div#inputs]
                                        ;(cljs.reader/read-string "[:input.search-box {:type \"text\", :placeholder \"Country name\"}] ")
                                        ]]
                            :spec     {:publish      {:query {:value ""}}
                                       :runQuery     (fn []
                                                         (this-as this
                                                                  (println (:query (js->clj (.-query this) :keywordize-keys true)))))
                                       :queryChanged (fn []
                                                         (this-as this
                                                                  (let [query (js->clj (.-query this) :keywordize-keys true)
                                                                        inputs (:inputs query)]
                                                                       )
                                                                  (.log js/console (.getElementById js/document "#inputs"))
                                                                  ))}})
```

As you can see I am trying to get the element by the id "inputs", however, it returns null.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHMw7.png
The div is in there, but I am not able to get it by its id. Is there a reason for this and is there a way to get it by its id? It was my understanding that get elementbyid will search through the shadow roots by apparently not..

EDIT: 
I found the answer by just fiddling around with the name of the shadow root as a property of an element!

```
    (p/defpolymer :query-component {:imports  ["components/polymer/polymer.html"]
                            :style    ".query-container
                             {margin: 20px;
                             display: inline-block;}"
                            :template [[:div.query-container
                                        [:div
                                         [:h4 {:style "display: inline-block;"} "Current Query"]
                                         [:button {:style    "float: right; margin-top: 10px;"
                                                   :on-click "{{runQuery}}"} "Run Query"]]
                                        [:span "{{query.name}}"]
                                        [:div#inputs]
                                        ;(cljs.reader/read-string "[:input.search-box {:type \"text\", :placeholder \"Country name\"}] ")
                                        ]]
                            :spec     {:publish      {:query {:value ""}}
                                       :runQuery     (fn []
                                                         (this-as this
                                                                  (println (:query (js->clj (.-query this) :keywordize-keys true)))))
                                       :queryChanged (fn []
                                                         (this-as this
                                                                  (let [query (js->clj (.-query this) :keywordize-keys true)
                                                                        inputs (:inputs query)
                                                                        shadow-root (.-shadowRoot this)
                                                                        input-div (.getElementById shadow-root "inputs")]
                                                                       (set! (.-innerHTML input-div) "<span>Shadow DOM</span>"))))}})
```

That is the working code. The shadow root is a property on your element and it is name "shadowRoot".

Comment: where does `p/defpolymer` comes from?

Comment: It is a way to define a polymer component in clojurescript. It is defined in another namespace.

Comment: Fwiw, Polymer puts a reference to any static node with an id in the `$` hash on your element. So `this.$.inputs` should reference the node in question.

Answer (score 1):

> > It was my understanding that getElementById will search through the shadow roots but apparently not.

None of the query methods on `document` will search through shadow roots, this is part of what makes them *shadowy*.

An exception to this rule is if you use `querySelector[All]` and a selector that specifically pierces shadow-roots, i.e. uses `/deep/` or `::shadow`).

Comment: For the record, we have a bit of an issue right this moment with QSA and `/deep/` under the polyfill, tracking ticket here: https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM/issues/436