# Programmatically change an element’s height from the outside

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, styling

I have four Polymer elements A-A, B-1, B-2, and X-X with X-X including A-A and B-1. B-1 is including B-2. The height of A-A should determine the height of B-2. I get the height of AA via the script `this.$.A-A.offsetHeight;` - so far so good.

**But how do I programmatically (via script) change element’s B-2 height?**

Even better would be to change the height of `.myB2class` in element B-2.

**Element X-X**

```
<polymer-element name="X-X" on-click="{{getHeight}}">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display:block;
      }
    </style>

    <A-A></A-A>

    <B-1></B-1>

  </template>
  <script>
    (function () {
      Polymer('X-X', {
        getHeight: function() {
        var heightAA = this.$.A-A.offsetHeight;
        console.log(height);
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**Partially succeeding...**

After trying everything what Google [threw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043786/polymer-get-element-by-id-from-shadow-root) [back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218859/can-i-access-the-shadow-dom-using-jquery) [at me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307907/listen-to-the-change-even-of-an-element-in-the-shadow-dom), I'm happy that at least this piece outputs something other than *null*:

```
var B2 = document.querySelectorAll("B-2::shadow .myB2class");
```

...more precisely console returns:

```
[div#x.flext-content-story-body, item: function, array: function]
 ›  0: div#x.flext-content-story-body
    length: 1
 ›  __proto__: NodeList
```

**BUT**, trying to set the height via `.style.height = heightAA;` returns undefined (same with static value "100px"). Oh, and then [reading something like this](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/styling-elements.html#programmatically-modifying-styles) is just to good to be true (tried it, no reaction, nada, no error, no output):

> You can dynamically change an element’s styling by, you guessed it,
>   modifying its .style property.
>
> From the outside:

```
var xFoo = document.createElement('x-foo');
xFoo.style.background = 'blue'; [e.g. xFoo.style.height = '100px']
```

I'm probably just overseeing a tiny detail so please, feel free to jump in.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your element name should contain a dash so something like 'x-x' and same goes with B1, B2 and AA.

As for selecting B2, try:

```
var B2 = document.querySelector("xx::shadow B1::shadow B2");
```

Comment: Yep, Polymer element names require a dash. Updated them just for clarity. Your suggestion does work! The problem was the  _All_ in _querySelectorAll_.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically change any polymer element’s height from the outside:

```
document.querySelector('any-polymer-element::shadow').style.height = "99px";
```

To programmatically change any div's height in any polymer element’s from the outside:

```
document.querySelector('any-polymer-element::shadow .any-div').style.height = "99px";
```

Thanks to Flying Emu for dropping the All in `document.querySelectorAll` which solves the problem. It was before my eyes in `0: div#x.flext-content-story-body` but I didn't see it!